# Jenkins with docker-compose

Tags: docker, jenkins, docker-compose

Running the docker-compose start command, via the Linux command line, the project is built and started correctly, but in the pipeline that I have built when running docker-compose up the following error occurs

ERROR: for php  Cannot start service php: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint bcc1dda8781b_ngweb-php-1 (58165db54561cd3ea0a34d3af1721084966d02b48a242321409840e25f109b9b): Error starting userland proxy: listen tcp4 0.0.0.0:443: bind: address already in

Does anyone have any idea what it could be?

Below are the docker-compose and Jenkinsfile files.

docker-compose.yaml

```
version: "3.1"
services:
  ngwebsite:
    image: jceleste/ngweb:115
    networks:
      - mysql_server
    ports:
      - 8282:80
    depends_on:
      - db
    links:
      - db
  db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    networks:
      - mysql_server
    command: --innodb_use_native_aio=0
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - db_data:/var/lib/mysql
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=*******
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=ngweb
    ports:
      - 3302:3306
volumes:
  db_data:
networks:
  mysql_server:
```

Jenkinsfile

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    
    environment { 
        registry = "jceleste/ngweb" 
        dockerImage = '' 
        tag_version = "${env.BUILD_ID}"     
        tag_generic  =  '{{TAG}}'
    }


    stages {
         stage ('Build Docker Image'){
             steps{
                 script {
                     dockerapp = docker.build("jceleste/ngweb:${env.BUILD_ID}", '-f ./Dockerfile ./ ')
                     
                }
             } 
        }   
        
        stage ('Push Docker Image'){
            steps {
                script {
                    docker.withRegistry('https://registry.hub.docker.com/','dockerhub'){
                     dockerapp.push("${env.BUILD_ID}")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        
        
        
        stage ('Deploy Docker Image'){
          
            steps{
                script {
                    sh 'sed -i "s/{{TAG}}/$tag_version/g" /home/ngweb-compose/docker-compose.yaml'
                    sh 'docker-compose start'
                    
                    sh 'sed -i "s/$tag_version/$tag_generic/g" /home/ngweb-compose/docker-compose.yaml'
                }
                
            }
           
        }
    }

}
```

That the pipeline correctly builds and starts the docker image

Comment: The error message means that something in the Compose file has `ports:` binding to the standard HTTPS port 443 on the host, but something else is already using this.  Your Compose file doesn't have this port, or a `php` service; do you have the right file?  `docker-compose start` would only restart containers in the strange state of existing but stopped; do you mean `docker-compose up -d` to apply any changes in the Compose file, deleting and recreating containers as necessary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As its been pointed out in the comment above, check your existing services or applications using port 443 on your host machine. Since you are using linux, use `sudo lsof -i :443`   to check for specific process using port 443. Stop the process if you can to free port or change port your compose file. I am assuming your webserver is running on Nginx.

So, i would change my **docker-compose.yaml** to

```
version: "3.1"
services:
  ngwebsite:
    image: jceleste/ngweb:115
    networks:
      - mysql_server
    ports:
      - "8282:443"
    depends_on:
      - db
    links:
      - db

  db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    networks:
      - mysql_server
    command: --innodb_use_native_aio=0
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - db_data:/var/lib/mysql
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=*******
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=ngweb
    ports:
      - "3302:3306"

volumes:
  db_data:

networks:
  mysql_server:
```

you can run `docker-compose up -d`  to start your services with the updated port mapping.

However, I am curious why your image is tagged `<115>` but different in Jenkinsfile. I would suppose you'd match them.